# python remove all date patterns from a text column of pandas dataframe

Tags: python

I have a csv file that i loaded using pd.read_csv. I have a column called summary. The text in that is of the form---
patients wants to reschedule epidural from 04/30, please call                                                                                                                    appointments     patients wants to reschedule epidural from 04/30, please call         ,  may 14, 2015 8:45 am      spoke with patient and r/s procedure but still will come in for medicines refill      phone call completed     becky wilson,  may 14, 2015 10:00 am

I want to get rid of all date and time formats eg.(01/02; 1/2/2015; 1/2/15 9:30 am; may 14, 2015, etc.) from the text. Please help me solve this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
df["Summary"].replace(
    {'\d+[\/:\-]\d+[\/:\-\s]*[\dAaPpMm]*' : '', '\w+\s\d+[\,]\s\d+' : ''},
    regex=True,
    inplace=True,
    )
```

You can very well tune in this regex as per your exact requirement.

Comment: Please mark as 'answer' if it solved your problem :)